# Showing a label in PrimeFaces when clicked on yes on popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a PrimeFaces popup and if I click yes on the popup it should show a label.

My code for popup:

```
<p:confirmDialog widgetVar="confirmDialog"
    visible="#{loadCouponGroupBean.displaypopUp =='true'}"
    showEffect="fade" id="confirmDialog" hideEffect="fade"
    message="#{msgs['msg.changeTemplate']}"
    header="#{msgs['msg.confirmation']}">
    <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button" 
        styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" update="itemDetailsId"
        onclick="PF('confirmDialog').hide()" />
    <p:commandButton value="No" type="button"
        styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close"
        onclick="PF('confirmDialog').hide()" />
</p:confirmDialog>
```

And my code for label:

```
<h:outputLabel id="itemDetailsId" value="#{loadCouponGroupBean.itemBo.name}" />
```

Based on this I need to show the label when the user clicks yes on the popup. How can I do this?

Comment: its quite straight forward, you can do this with either javascript or jsf, using the css "display" attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You should assign the variable used in h:outputLabel a value.

```
value="#{loadCouponGroupBean.itemBo.name}"
```

You can assign it a value when clicking on Yes button by calling a method in a jsf bean. Change you Yes button to the following

```
<p:commandButton value="Yes" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" update="itemDetailsId" action="loadCouponGroupBean.changeName()"  onclick="PF('confirmDialog').hide()" />
```

Then create a changeName method in your bean

```
public void changeName(){
   name="New Value";
}
```